# Multiplicative operator from L1 to L1 is given by an L_inf function

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Problem: Let $\phi :X\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a measurable function with respect to a measure space $(X,\mu)$.  Suppose that $\phi f\in L^1(X,\mu)$ whenever $f\in L^1(X,\mu)$ and define $M_\phi :f\rightarrow \phi f$ on $L^1(X,\mu)$.  Show that $M_\phi$ is continuous, that $\phi \in L^\infty (X,\mu)$, and that $\| M_\phi \| \leq \| \phi \|_{\infty}$.

I am able to show that $M_\phi$ is continuous by applying the Closed Graph Theorem.  Also, $\| M_\phi \| \leq \| \phi \|_{\infty}$ is implied by Holder's Inequality.  My trouble is with showing $\phi \in L^\infty (X,\mu)$.  I wanted to use the dual of $L^1$, but I don't have that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite (so I can't apply the Riesz Representation Theorem for $p=1$ and $q=\infty$, I think).

Any ideas are greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem becomes very pathological if you don't assume $(X,\mu)$ to be $\sigma$-finite.

For example, it is false if you consider the space $X =\{a,b\}$ equipped with the measure $\mu$ such that $\mu(\{a\}) = 1$ and $\mu(\{b\}) = \infty$. Consider the function $\phi(x)= \infty \cdot \chi_{\{b\}}(x)$. This is clearly not in $L^\infty$. However any $L^1$ function must be $0$ on $b$, so $\phi f = f$ for all $f \in L^1$, so in particular $\phi f \in L^1$ for all $f \in L^1$.